# web add-in load issues on Outlook desktop only

Tags: javascript, reactjs, outlook, office-js

I've got a problem where my add-in is running fine in Outlook Online, but won't run in Outlook desktop.  The add-in is successfully activated from the manifest, but fails after load.  This is a React + TypeScript project (testing using NodeJS + webpack in Webstorm).

I've narrowed the problem to the usage of ANY require statement for importing a reference.  If I eliminate it, it runs fine and shows my test Office UI Fabric CompoundButton component.  With the code, it spins and eventually shows a blank page. No script exceptions are thrown, and this is enabled in IE settings.

Why would this fail only on the desktop?

To repro, use three files:

- Start/main page: myapp.tsx
- Which renders TestComponent.tsx
- Which references test.jsx

```
//myapp.tsx
import TestComponent from './components/TestComponent';
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { AppContainer } from 'react-hot-loader';

const render = (Component) => {

    ReactDOM.render(
        
            
        ,
        document.getElementById('container')
    );
};

Office.initialize = function () {

    $(document).ready(function () {

        console.log('====myapp.tsx.Office.initialize(): entered');

        render(TestComponent);
    });
};

if ((module as any).hot) {

    console.log('====index.tsx.module() foo');

    (module as any).hot.accept('./components/App', () => {
        const NextApp = require('./components/App').default;
        render(NextApp);
    });
}

//TestComponent.tsx

import * as React from 'react';
import { CompoundButton } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Button';

//============
// BAD CODE!
//import foo = require('../scripts/test.jsx');
//============

export default class TestComponent extends React.Component {

    render() {

        console.log('====TestComponent.render()');

        //============
        // BAD CODE!
        //foo.testFunction();
        //============

        return(
            
                Create account
            
        );
    }
}

//test.jsx

export function testFunction(){
    console.log("test.jsx: testFunction");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Office 2013 and 2016 for Windows (desktop apps) use an embedded IE 11 browser for rendering. IE 11 doesn't support [a lot of the recent JS features](http://html5test.com/compare/browser/ie-11/edge-18/chrome-68/firefox-60.html) you find in Edge, Chrome, and Firefox. As such, you either need to polyfill the functionality you need to provide alternative paths for IE 11.

One quick-fix may be just changing how TypeScript is generating JS so that it is compatible with IE 11:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "lib": [ "es5", "dom", "es2015.promise" ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Marc, I'll definitely keep IE 11 in mind as I do a review. However after hacking away and trying a few things I was able to get that simple require reference to work, so we can rule that out. The issue actually seems to be due to unresolved dev dependency references in a referenced js module, which the compiler oddly wasn't catching before.